# Orbeon xforms using function

Tags: orbeon, xforms

In a xhtml-tag is attribute 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
and i try to use the code

```
<xhtml:head>
    <xforms:model>
        <xforms:function signature="fn($a as xsd:string) as xsd:string">
            <xforms:return value="concat($a,$a,$a)"/>
        </xforms:function>
    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
```

how to use correctly this function

```
<xhtml:body>
    <xforms:output ref="fn('bla')"/>
</xhtml:body>
```

that can see string "blablabla" instread of an error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `<xforms:function>` element is a new XForms 2.0 element which is not yet implemented in Orbeon Forms. This explains why your example doesn't work.